# Writing a query for Ivanti database survey

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wrote a query to help output the survey questions on a database within a particular time frame but it keeps giving me an error. The code is:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM FRS_SURVEYRESULTS
WHERE Identifier = (SELECT RecId
                    FROM Incident
                    WHERE ClosedDateTime BETWEEN '2021-01-30 12:46:56.270' AND '2022-01-30 12:46:56.270');
```

The error it gives me is

[image: error code]

What I'm trying to achieve is to output all the `FRS_SURVEYRESULTS` within that time range.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Also you don't need to SHOUT at us in the title.

Comment: Images are bad - blurry, cropped, and poorly enlarged ones are worse. And writing code like `ClosedDateTime BETWEEN '2021-01-30 12:46:56.270' AND '2022-01-30 12:46:56.270'` takes more effort to read and understand than `ClosedDateTime = '2021-01-30 12:46:56.270'` - so why use the former?

Comment: The error is clear (not clear in readable from your blurry image but in meaning). Your subquery returns more than 1 result. Your query is the same as if you would write SELECT* FROM FRS_SERVEYRESULTS WHERE Identifier = (1 and also 2 and also 3 and also 4 and so on...)

Answer (score 0):

use this for One RecId

```
select * from FRS_SURVEYRESULTS 
where Identifier = (select top 1 RecId FROM Incident 
                    WHERE ClosedDateTime BETWEEN 
                    '2021-01-30 12:46:56.270' AND '2022-01-30 12:46:56.270')
```

use this For All RecId

```
select * from FRS_SURVEYRESULTS 
where Identifier in (select RecId FROM Incident 
                      WHERE ClosedDateTime BETWEEN 
                      '2021-01-30 12:46:56.270' AND '2022-01-30 12:46:56.270')
```

Comment: I doubt the first option, with a `TOP 1` will work as desired, If the arbitrary value of `RecID` isn't the value of  `Identifier` you won't get a match, though I suspect the OP would like that row returned.

Comment: it's depended on user it use `top 1` or `distinct` both op are open.

Comment: `TOP 1` stops the error, yes, but it doesn't solve the problem; it just produces a different one.

Comment: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e9d19984a774849e63a7e4d996af01d8) note your queries give different results.